# masm assembly how to use getpixel to build a color picker

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, masm

I would like to build a color picker. I have tried this code

```
invoke GetDC,NULL
mov esi,eax
invoke GetPixel,esi,400,400
invoke lstrcpy,string ,eax
invoke SetDlgItemText,hWin,textbox1,string
invoke ReleaseDC,NULL,esi
```

but it returns `P»©` and things like that. how do I get it to return things like `00F0F0F0h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to format a string but a number, you need to pass the correct flags and specifier to wsprintf.  What *printf does is format whatever you pass to it, and it will convert to a string according to your format specifier and put that string into the address passed to `lpOut`.

The `%s` specifier is for formatting strings.  Lets say I wanted to display the return value of `GetPixel` as an 8 digit hex number with 0x in front of the number.

```
.data
szFmt       db  "%#08x", 0

.data?
Buf         db  12 dup (?)

.code
    invoke  GetDC, NULL
    invoke  GetPixel, eax, 200, 200

    invoke  wsprintf, offset Buf, offset szFmt, eax
    invoke  MessageBox, NULL, offset Buf, NULL, MB_OK
```

Instead of calling `MessageBox`, you can do:

```
invoke  SetDlgItemText, hWin, textbox1, offset Buf
```

Try that and see what `MessageBox` displays

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thank you so much that works great and now I understand wsprintf a little better

Answer (score 2):

The [`GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909.aspx) function returns a `COLORREF` value (which is really just a `DWORD` that specifies the RGB value of the pixel).

But your code treats the return value of `GetPixel` as if it were a string, passing it to `lstrcpy`. That won't work. `lstrcpy` is going to interpret it as if it were a pointer to a string somewhere in memory.

And that explains why you're getting nonsense like `P»©`, because the `GetPixel` function doesn't really return a memory address and the memory at that address doesn't really contain a valid nul-terminated string.

If you want to display a formatted numeric value as a string, you need to use a `printf`-style function to accomplish this. The Win32 API variant is called [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx).

Comment: could you show me an example because I am new to assembly and have never used wsprintf and I tried to invoke it but it is giving me an error. thanks

Comment: @tandpcat There are a couple of tricky parts. First, `wsprintf` uses a C-style calling convention, rather than stdcall, so you have to balance the stack after calling it. But if I remember correctly, the fancy `INVOKE` directive should handle that ugliness for you. Second, you have to pass addresses as arguments to the function. You should be able to use the `ADDR` directive for that. Something like: `invoke wsprintf, ADDR myBuffer, ADDR myFormat, eax`. Check your manual or tutorial for more. I'm foggy on the details. I haven't nearly enough free time to write programs by hand in assembler.

Comment: I treid this wsprintf PROTO C buffer:DWORD,format:DWORD,args:VARARG       then in the code   invoke wsprintf, ADDR gettext1, ADDR format, eax   and got errors             syntax error : PROTO  this is my data   gettext1 is              gettext1 DB 20 DUP(?)
my format is        format db "%s%s",0

Comment: okay so I tried invoke wsprintf, addr gettext1, "%s", eax  and nothing shows up in the textbox. i tried a few other formats but they give like 0 or 11000000